# Form action not working in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to insert data in database. i found a problem. I have 2 blade.php page. 1. dashboard.blade.php and another is class.blade.php.
When i use in my form action dashboard.blade.php its working. but when i used in action class.blade.php its not working. i can't found this problem. Here is my form action :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/dashboard') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
```

when i changed it

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/class') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
```

then its not working.
Here is my controller

```
public function showclass(Request $request)
{
    $randomnumber = rand(50001,1000000);

    $classrooms = new Classrooms();
    $classrooms->class_name = $request['class_name'];
    $classrooms->subject_name = $request['subject_name'];
    $classrooms->section = $request['section'];
    $classrooms->class_code = $randomnumber;
    $classrooms -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $classrooms -> save();
    Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
    //return redirect(route('dashboard'));
    return view('dashboard', array('classroom' => Auth::user()) );
}
```

Comment: what error you getting? are the showclass function ever ge called? if yes what does $class->save() give you? true or false?

Comment: There are no error shown. just when i put in action "dashboard" then its working and data inserted. but when i used "class" its view class.blade page but data not insert.

Comment: ok does save() give you true or false? does the controller action even fired? you need to answer this questions in your question we cant guess whats happening

Comment: its true when i use dashboard in action. its false when i used class.blade.

Comment: so you have some error in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your Route. You have used `showdata` method instead of `showclass`. Just change it like below:

```
Route::post('/class', [
'uses' => 'classroom@showclass',
'as' => 'classrooms']);
```

**Note:** Make sure to specify specific method while defining the routes.