# I can't insert data in database laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to insert data in my database.But I can't to do it. I try my best. I know its a simple question.
Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/class', [
'uses' => 'classroom@showdata',
'as' => 'classrooms']);
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function showclass(Request $request)
{
    $randomnumber = rand(50001,1000000);

    $classrooms = new Classrooms();
    $classrooms->class_name = $request['class_name'];
    $classrooms->subject_name = $request['subject_name'];
    $classrooms->section = $request['section'];
    $classrooms->class_code = $randomnumber;
    $classrooms -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $classrooms -> save();
    return view('class', array('classroom' => Auth::user()) );
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/class') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Make sure you have the `debug` set to `true` in your `config/app.php`. Then  wait for the stack trace of the thrown exception (if any, but highly likely) to know the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your Route. You have used `showdata` method instead of `showclass`. Just change it like below:

```
Route::post('/class', [
'uses' => 'classroom@showclass',
'as' => 'classrooms']);
```

**Note:** Make sure to specify specific method while defining the routes.

Comment: can you check if your function is executing ? use `die();`

Comment: how its used i don't know. there is most funny things is i have a another blade page dashboard.blade.php if i changed in route url ... controller return and form action in dashboard its works

Comment: your previous question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067623/form-action-not-working-in-laravel

Comment: can you post dashboard route and method used ?

Comment: to use `die()` add `die('hello');` in your above method.

Comment: if, your method is executing, it will print hello

Comment: if i used this Route::post('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'classroom@showclass',
    'as' => 'class'
]); and <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/dashboard') }}"> its working... but when i edit dashboard to class and action also then its not working..

Comment: that's weird... is it possible that you might have defined 2 same routes ? just asking

Comment: sure.. id and pwd?

Comment: id: 340 303 785 pass:8012

Comment: @Shuvo. With those information you give. This answer is completely correct. Vote up this answer and update your question!